# How to keep a user logged into my website using a php session cookie

Tags: php, session

Initially I came up with the following to see if a user is already logged in:

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionid'])) {
   header("Location: login_form.php");
  } else {
   echo "You are logged in";
  }
?>
```

`$_SESSION['sessionid']` is set when the user manually logs in.

If the user checks "remember me" I set the session cookie's lifetime to be 10 years:

```
   $lifetime = 24*60*60*365*10; // 10 years
   setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+ $lifetime,'/');
```

So now I need to figure out what to do on the server side....  Initially I was thinking of setting session.gc_maxlifetime to a high value so that the server's session data would live for a long time, but 10 years would be ridiculous.  Now I'm thinking I should store the session ID in the user table and query that against the session ID.  If there's a match, I'll auto log the user in.

My question is:
 How do I get the session ID from the client?

My understanding is that it will be available after I call session_start(), but only if the server's session data is still available.  If the session has expired (which happens depending on the value of session.gc_maxlifetime) a new session ID will get generated when session_start() is called.  This would be problematic as it wouldn't match the last session ID that I stored in the user table.

So the ideas I have to read the session ID, after calling session_start() are:
1) `$_SESSION['sessionid']`
2) `$id = session_id();`
3) `$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];`

1 and 2 won't work if the server has destroyed the session data, so I don't think I can use these.

3 might work, but when I tried it (`echo $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];`) I was surprised because the session ID was appeared twice:
the output was this:

```
htknitopug4b6bv4ql9050pfg6 //htknitopug4b6bv4ql9050pfg6
```

I simply expected the output to be `htknitopug4b6bv4ql9050pfg6.`

Can anyone explain the duplicate entry of the session ID?  If this behavior is consistent I could always read the first string into my database table.

Comment: I would suggest you give [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009685/encoding-cookies-so-they-cannot-be-spoofed-or-read-etc/5009903#5009903) a read.  In short, you shouldn't do that...

Comment: I think 10years is way too long.

Comment: I just looked at cookies on my computer and saw some from amazon that expire in 2037.  I couldn't see the harm in making them live forever (i.e. 10 years).

Comment: ircmaxell, thanks for the link.  I think my method of using a session ID is fine.  I can regenerate the session ID each time the user visits for added security.  Plus I'm storing hashed versions of passwords in the database.  Any chance you know the answers to the two questions I posted?

Comment: @user418: **Session** cookies that live that long are bad.  Tracking and remember-me cookies that live that long are just fine.  But sessions should be kept short...  Have a separate remember-me function.  If when you start the session, it detects a new one, then lookup the remember me cookie and test that to auto-login (I'd highly recommend signing it as in the linked answer).  The session identifier should not be abused like that.  (And i hope you're not just storing a raw hash, use a salt).  What was the other question?

Comment: Ok, you're starting to convince me... ;-)

Comment: The second question was why did the session cookie contain two session IDs?  The same ID was echoed twice with slashes in between (the slashes look like C++ comments).

Comment: @user41: It must be an error in your program.  Check the cookies sent by your browser to verify...

Comment: I would mark as answered, but I don't see a button to do that

Comment: @user41: I've added a summary of the comments as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you shouldn't do that.  For reasons why, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009685/encoding-cookies-so-they-cannot-be-spoofed-or-read-etc/5009903#5009903).

As far as what to do instead, I would set a signed cookie (that post shows how) with a large random string unique for each user.  Then, when loading the session if it is new, check for the cookie.  Then look up the user based on that random string.  If you find one, silently log the user back in.

This is a pretty standard remember-me function, but it avoids the pitfals of having long-running sessions, or using the session identifier for other things.

One thing to note, you really should be rotating your session identifier pretty often as well.  I typically do it for every login/logout event as well as whenever the user does something sensitive (admin forms, posting content, etc).  There's nothing wrong with rotating too much...