# Zend Framework 2 session container lifetime

Tags: session, cookies, zend-framework2, authorization

I'm a nowise in ZF2 and need an advise from more experienced users.
I'm developing a small shop I want to make different lifetime for session storage and cookies. 
For example when user logins server sends a cookie with 3 months lifetime and creates  session storage record (for user data) with lifetime 30 minutes. Having cookie and unique session record user can buy goods, comment, and view their profile with secure data (e.g. credit card number, phone, etc).
After 30 minutes of no activity session record must be deleted but cookie must be left (cookies lifetime must be 3 months). Having only cookie user can make comments but can not buy anything or view his/her profile. 
So my I'm interesting how can I realize it with ZF2 ? - As I understood "remember_me_time" must be equal to "cookie_lifetime" or they can be changed to different values ?
Does ZF2 have any standard mechanism to delete a session storage after some time for single user or I have to create such mechanism by myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ZfcUser (and if you're doing user authentication on ZF2 you should be) check out the `GoalioRememberMe`(https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMe) module, it does exactly what you're looking for (Caveat: I've never actually used it myself so I can't vouch for it's efficacy or security)

I also suggest reading [this response by Anthony Ferrara (@ircmaxell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009685/encoding-cookies-so-they-cannot-be-spoofed-or-read-etc/5009903#5009903) to a somewhat similar question.  It contains some background information on what you should and shouldn't do, and the gist of it is: don't try to keep the PHP session open that long, use a "remember me" cookie instead and build a new session from the remember-me cookie for visitors that don't have an active session.