# Login using Zend2 and LDAP - disconnecting after some time

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, ldap

I'm using Zend2 with LDAP to authenticate users.

But when the system stays idle for some time, it auto disconnect.

Here are some information:

```
$ldap = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Service\Ldap');
$user = $ldap->authenticate($username, $password);
$session = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SessionStorage');
```

How can I increase the time or disable auto disconnect?

Comment: Do you mean that the session expires and so the user is no longer signed in?

Comment: Doesn't look like an LDAP issue but a session timeout. Or are you calling the authenticate method on every request?

Comment: Yes @AdamLundrigan, the sessions expires and the user have to login again.

Comment: @heiglandreas, you right, it is a session timeout.
The system verify the user session in each page the user enter.

I don't know where I can change this timeout to make it larger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the session expiry time you want via the SessionManager.  An example of this can be found [here on the ZfcUser wiki](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-configure-a-session-timeout) (the procedure not ZfcUser-specific)

If you want to extend the lifetime of the session beyond a reasonable single-visit timeframe (ie: >30 minutes) you should use something like [GoalioRememberMe](https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMe)***** as there are security implications to keeping a single session open for too long ([read the section "Do NOT Use Long-Running Sessions!" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009685/encoding-cookies-so-they-cannot-be-spoofed-or-read-etc/5009903#5009903))

***** = it's ZfcUser-specific so you'll need to implement your own if you're not using that

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll try and post the result here later.